# Qooxdoo binding multi list in form

Tags: qooxdoo

I can't seem to get qooxdoo 5.0.1 to properly bind a multi-selection list to a form. When I bind it like any other control, the model only ever gets one of the selected items in the list, not all of the selected items.

I note that in qx.data.controller.Form, there are a number of statements similar to:

```
this.__isModelSelectable(item) ? "modelSelection[0]" : "value"
```

Using "modelSelection[0]" instead of "modelSelection" implies that the binding is only ever getting the first selected item intentionally.

If this is true, how is a form supposed to get all the selected items from a multi-select list?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the form controller doesn't support multi-selection, so it's the default behavior that it always get only the first selected item.

Currently I'm also looking for a solution or a workaround for this.